# need help with Z score answer

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

A man with a Z score =2.13. if the sample is normally distributed of the population of interest, approximately what Percent of the population would have a Z score of -2.13.

I use the z score table and received answer 1.7.

Comment: How is the original man with a different score relative to the problem? As for the problem statement, do you mean what percentage are $-2.13$ *or below*? There's a $0$ probability of being exactly any given value.

Comment: yes what percentage

Comment: Then I agree with your answer. I recommend updating your question to reflect what you clarified.